# Python: Is there any difference between "del a" and "del(a)"?

Tags: python

As far as I can tell, both `del a` and `del(a)` seems to work with the same effect. If that's the case, why would Python allow `del` to exist both as a statement and a function?

Comment: Parentheses don't always signify functions. You can also do `1+(2)` but that doesn't mean `1+` is a function.

Comment: This question is neither unclear nor too broad, it's simply a misunderstanding of the role parentheses play in Python grammar, which is not crazy coming from a beginner.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`del` is always a statement. Using parenthesis doesn't mean you're making a function call, but you're grouping expressions. `(1)` is just the same as `1`.

Comment: And, quite obviously, `(a)` is also the same as just `a`. Refering to OP's expample.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Juhana 's comment and @cdonts 's answer. Apparently parentheses here do not represent a function call. Here's another example:

```
In [40]: a=b=c=1
In [41]: del[a,(b,c)]
In [42]: b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-42-60b725f10c9c>", line 1, in <module>
    b
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```